# unable to apply flex to imported styled component

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Im importing a styled component into another component and trying to move it by putting it in a View and using flex to push it to the bottom of the screen.  Though in doing so the "styled component is not acting like a child of the View I place it in.  This is limiting the reusability of my styled components.  I'm questioning the use of styled-components now.

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ThemeContext from '../../../providers/ThemeProvider';
import {TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';

const Button = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: ${props=> props.theme.primaryColor};
  border-radius: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
`;

export const AuthButton = props => {
  return (
    <Button onPress={() => props.onPress()}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#fff'}}>{props.text}</Text>
    </Button>
  );
};




<Wrapper>
        <View style={{borderColor:'lime', borderWidth: 1, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
        <AuthButton text="Logout" onPress={()=> logoutUser()}/>
        </View>
    </Wrapper>
```

[image]

Comment: ^the styled component is not in the View container, and not flexing to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Can you provide the code of `AuthButton` ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but you need to use flexdirection before justify-content.
Example:

```
 <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  }}>
```

in your case you should use:

```
<Wrapper>
        <View style={{borderColor:'lime', borderWidth: 1, flex: 1,  flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <AuthButton text="Logout" onPress={()=> logoutUser()}/>
        </View>
    </Wrapper>
```

Comment: tried adding flexDirection:'row', the styled-component "AuthButton" still is not inside the "<View>" tag :(

Comment: better check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)

Comment: const Button = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: ${props=> props.theme.primaryColor};
  border-radius: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
`;

export const AuthButton = props => {
  // const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext)
  // console.log(theme)
  return (
    <Button onPress={() => props.onPress()}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#fff'}}>{props.text}</Text>
    </Button>
  );
};

Comment: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components this is not an error...

Comment: you're correct, Im not posting an error.  Although styled components are worthless to me if I can't use them in other components as a child in a View container.  Was posting to see if anyone had additional insight into this behavior as it could be a result of me improperly using styled-components.  The documentation for styled components does specifically refer to this use case for react native or this behavior directly.

Answer (score 0):

For what ever reason flex properties aren't working for child components that are nested inside a View tag, so I'm using top instead.

```
        <Wrapper style={{flex: 1,borderColor:'lime', borderWidth: 1}}>
          <View style={{top: '85%'}}>
            <AuthButton text="Logout" onPress={()=> logoutUser()}/>
          </View>
        </Wrapper>
```